# SQL query is taking a long time to execute

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have researched other questions and tried their solutions, but none helped me. How can I lower the execution time of this query?

```
SELECT c.id,c.title,c.time,u.username, (SELECT time FROM comments_read as io WHERE io.id=c.id AND io.uid=$logged_userid LIMIT 1) as read_time 
FROM comments as c 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.uid=c.uid 
WHERE c.deleted=0 
ORDER by c.time DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have indexes set on all of the link fields?

Comment: Using a join instead of an inner select subquery may help.

Comment: don't use a corelated subquery. that can easily be done a simple join and `max()`

Comment: and in addition to what Gordon said, don't expect `limit` to speed things up any, when using order by (other than line speed payload delivery) as it still has to resolve the set

Comment: This `(SELECT time FROM comments_read as io WHERE io.id=c.id AND io.uid=$logged_userid LIMIT 1)` Executes 1 time each for each record in C.  Thus is similar to a loop.  you'd be better off joining to comments_read and manaing it as  "SET." Generally SET based logic in RDBMS process faster than potentially hundreds of simple queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.time, u.username,
       (SELECT io.time
        FROM comments_read as io 
        WHERE io.id = c.id AND
              io.uid = $logged_userid
        LIMIT 1
       ) as read_time
FROM comments as c LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON u.uid = c.uid
WHERE c.deleted = 0
ORDER by c.time DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Indexes can be used to improve performance.  I would start with `comments(deleted, time, uid, id)`, `users(uid)`, and `comments_read(id, uid, time)`.

Note:  using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is usually discouraged, because the results are unstable.  You can get any matching row.

EDIT:

If the above indexes do not help, they might be getting confused by the `JOIN`.  You can do the same thing as:

```
SELECT c.id, c.title, c.time,
       (SELECT u.username FROM users u WHERE u.uid = c.uid) as username,
       (SELECT io.time
        FROM comments_read as io 
        WHERE io.id = c.id AND
              io.uid = $logged_userid
        LIMIT 1
       ) as read_time
FROM comments as c 
WHERE c.deleted = 0
ORDER by c.time DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

This should take advantage of the above indexes and have no "file sort" step to slow things down.